# How to insert same value to entire column in sqlite3?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

I need to insert a text to entire column in the table. Column is having 200 rows. I need to insert the same value into entire 200 rows of the same column...

How could I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
UPDATE `Table` SET `Column` = 'value'
```

Just with no WHERE clause

Comment: i haven't inserted any value into the column its a new column?is this one will work

Comment: This will always set the entire column to a value no matter how old the column is. Unless you haven't even created the column yet in which case you need to do an `ALTER TABLE \`Table\` ADD COLUMN \`Column\``