# sqlite: import csv into table

Tags: sqlite, csv, import

I have a table with the following column structure:

```
sqlite> create table stocks(stockticker varchar(4), tradedate date, open double, high double, low double, close double, volume integer, adjclose double);
```

What I want to do is save daily stock data for a group of stocks into this one table but populate it with whatever historical data that currently exists. So I saved the historicals for XLI from yahoo/finance into a file called XLI.csv

In mySQL I use to be able to do the following:

```
sqlite> LOAD DATA INLINE 'XLI.csv'
   ...> INTO TABLE stocks
   ...> FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
   ...> LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
   ...> IGNORE 1 LINES
   ...> (@tradedate, open, high, low, close, volume, adjclose)
   ...> SET stockticker = 'XLI',
   ...> tradedate = STR_TO_DATE(@tradedate, '%m/%d/%Y');
Error: near "LOAD": syntax error
sqlite>
```

Now I understand SQLITE has many differences but I am a newbie and all the examples I have found typically have the following command structure:

```
sqlite> .import <filename> <table>
```

This does not help me because I need to also set the 'stockticker' field, ignore the first line (headers) and ensure the date is imported correctly. I haven't found any examples in the documentation or on the internet that shows something like what I want to do.

I would kindly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

import the raw data into a staging table, then select the contents into the tick table (add a where condition to ignore the values from the first line)

to convert the date string, you can create a valid [sqlite date string](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) (e.g.: yyyy-mm-dd) by re-arranging the original date string and insert that into the destination date column.

```
insert into tick (stockticker, tradedate, open, high, low, close, volume, adjclose)
  select stockticker, (substr(date, 7) || '-' || substr(date, 1, 2) || '-' || substr(date, 4, 2)),
  open, high, low, close, volume, adjclose from stage
```

Comment: Thanks jspcal. I created a staging table that does not have the stockticker column since there isn't a column for that in the .csv file. If I want to now execute the code you have provided how do I *set* the stockticker field to "XLI" for example? Appreciate your help.

Comment: I meant how do I set/insert the stockticker field for every row in the tick table? I have copied all of the content in the staging table into the tick table but the only thing I need to do now is set the stock ticker field.

Comment: I found it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6728738/how-to-insert-same-value-to-entire-column-in-sqlite3